Probability that two paths don't intersect
This question is inspired by this other question but it could be simpler. I think also that by using an answer here and the inclusion-exclusion principle we can get a solution for the linked question.
Suppose that $2$ "hamsters" are at the points $(1,n)$, $(m,n)$ in the plane, where m and n are positive integers and $m \ge 2$. They walk independently one step east with probability $p$ or one step south with probability $1-p$, until
reaching the $x$-axis (at points $(k_1,0)$ and $(k_2,0)$).
What is the probability, computed with elementary methods, that their paths don't intersect? According to the linked question, the answer for $m = 2$ and $n = 2$ should be $\frac{1-p}{1+p}$.
Any idea?

I'd prefer to let the starting positions be $(a,n) $ and $(a+d,n)$ with $d>0$.
The probaiility thet the left hamster runs right into the right hamster's starting position, is $p^d$.
If this does not happen, then the hamsters will both enter row $n-1$ at some time and at some points $(a',n-1)$ and $(a'+d',n-1)$. You can find the probability distribution for $d'$ and then might use this and some generatingfunctionology to obtain a general result.
